# WA business api nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, facebook, whatsapp, facebook-chatbot

I have a problem with my nodejs code and the connection to the official whatsapp business api.

The bot connects the webhook correctly, the messages arrive to the server correctly but the code I have implemented to make it respond is not being effective, I checked the code from top to bottom but I can't find the fault.

I leave you the codes so you have more context:

whatsappController.js:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const myConsole = new console.Console(fs.createWriteStream("./logs.txt"));
const whatsappService = require("../services/whatsappService")

const VerifyToken = (req, res) => {

    try {
        var accessToken = "456E7GR****************************";
        var token = req.query["hub.verify_token"];
        var challenge = req.query["hub.challenge"];

        if(challenge != null && token != null && token == accessToken){
            res.send(challenge);
        }
        else{
            res.status(400).send();
        }
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(400).send();
    }
}

const ReceivedMessage = (req, res) => {
    try {
        var entry = (req.body["entry"])[0];
        var changes = (entry["changes"])[0];
        var value = changes["value"];
        var messageObject = value["messages"];

        if(typeof messageObject != "undefined"){
            var messages = messageObject[0];
            var text = GetTextUser(messages);
            var number = messages["from"];

            myConsole.log("Message: " + text + " from: " + number);
            whatsappService.SendMessageWhatsApp("The user say: " + text, number);
            
            myConsole.log(messages);
            myConsole.log(messageObject);
        }

        res.send("EVENT_RECEIVED");
    }catch(e) {
        myConsole.log(e);
        res.send("EVENT_RECEIVED");
    }
}

function GetTextUser(messages){
    var text = "";
    var typeMessage = messages["type"];
    if(typeMessage == "text"){
        text = (messages["text"])["body"];
    }
    else if(typeMessage == "interactive"){
        var interactiveObject = messages["interactive"];
        var typeInteractive = interactiveObject["type"];

        if(typeInteractive == "button_reply"){
            text = (interactiveObject["button_reply"])["title"];
        }
        else if(typeInteractive == "list_reply"){
            text = (interactiveObject["list_reply"])["title"];
        }else{
            myConsole.log("sin mensaje");
        }
    }else{
        myConsole.log("sin mensaje");
    }
    return text;
}

module.exports = {
    VerifyToken,
    ReceivedMessage
}
```

The second file is whatsappService which I make the connection with the api using the token and I also send the format of the message I want to send when I receive a hello for example...

```
const https = require("https");
function SendMessageWhatsApp(textResponse, number){
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",    
        "recipient_type": "individual",
        "to": number,
        "type": "text",
        "text": {
            "preview_url": false,
            "body": textResponse
        }
    });

    const options = {
        host:"graph.facebook.com",
        path:"/v15.0/1119744*************/messages",
        method:"POST",
        body:data,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            Authorization:"Bearer EAAWNbICfuWEBAK5ObPbD******************************************************"
        }
    };
    const req = https.request(options, res => {
        res.on("data", d=> {
            process.stdout.write(d);
        });
    });

    req.on("error", error => {
        console.error(error);
    });

    req.write(data);
    req.end();
}

module.exports = {
    SendMessageWhatsApp
};
```

Then I declare the routes for the get (to check token) and post (to receive and reply to messages) methods:

```
const expres = require("express");
const router = expres.Router();
const whatsappController = require("../controllers/whatsappControllers");

router
.get("/", whatsappController.VerifyToken)
.post("/", whatsappController.ReceivedMessage)

module.exports = router;
```

Last but not least the index file for the code to run correctly:

```
const express = require("express");
const apiRoute = require("./routes/routes");

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/whatsapp", apiRoute);

app.listen(PORT, () => (console.log("El puerto es: " + PORT)));
```

I should clarify that I did the tests with Postman and they were all successful, it responds and receives messages correctly, finally I did the tests by uploading the bot to the Azure service and it works without problem until it has to answer/replicate the user's message.

The bot is not responding to the user when he talks to it but everything arrives correctly to the server and it processes it with a 200 response. I attach the evidence that there is no problem in the reception.

[image]

Finally I must say that in the meta platform I have everything configured as specified by the same platform, I have already configured the api to answer the messages through the webhooks and everything is correct, I just can't get the bot to answer correctly.

The bot is hosted in the Azure service.

[image]

Comment: Solved: some numbers have a problema with the api of WAB in my country (Argentina) the phone numbers start in +54 9 11. The problem is the 9 in the phone number, and this have a conflict in the servers of meta, Solution quit number 9 to numbers of this country and the message will send to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: some numbers have a problema with the api of WAB in my country (Argentina) the phone numbers start in +54 9 11. The problem is the 9 in the phone number, and this have a conflict in the servers of meta, Solution quit number 9 to numbers of this country and the message will send to user.